# How to solve IndexError: list index out of range Python?

Tags: python

Im new at coding and when i start this program i got an Message:

question_solve.answer2 = request_data.json()[parameter][i]["choices"][2]["answer"]
IndexError: list index out of range

I have no idea how to solve it...
Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

parameter = "questions"

url = "https://create.kahoot.it/rest/kahoots/"
uuid = input("Enter UUID: ")
NumOfQuestions = int(input("Enter Num of Questions: "))

class question:
    def __init__(self):
        self.answer0 = None
        self.correct0 = None
        self.answer1 = None
        self.correct1 = None
        self.answer2 = None
        self.correct2 = None
        self.answer3 = None
        self.correct3 = None

class true_false:
    def __init__(self):
        self.answer1 = None
        self.answer2 = None

request_data = requests.get(url + uuid) #Get Json Data

i = 0
question_solve = question()

for i in range(NumOfQuestions):
    Type_Of_Question = request_data.json()["questions"][i]["type"]

    if Type_Of_Question == "quiz" or Type_Of_Question ==  "multiple_select_quiz":
        question_solve.answer0 = request_data.json()[parameter][i]["choices"][0]["answer"]
        question_solve.correct0 = request_data.json()[parameter][i]["choices"][0]["correct"]

        question_solve.answer1 = request_data.json()[parameter][i]["choices"][1]["answer"]
        question_solve.correct1 = request_data.json()[parameter][i]["choices"][1]["correct"]

        question_solve.answer2 = request_data.json()[parameter][i]["choices"][2]["answer"]
        question_solve.correct2 = request_data.json()[parameter][i]["choices"][2]["correct"]

        question_solve.answer3 = request_data.json()[parameter][i]["choices"][3]["answer"]
        question_solve.correct3 = request_data.json()[parameter][i]["choices"][3]["correct"]

        print("Question",i+1,": ")
        print(question_solve.answer0, "=", question_solve.correct0)
        print(question_solve.answer1, "=", question_solve.correct1)
        print(question_solve.answer2, "=", question_solve.correct2)
        print(question_solve.answer3, "=", question_solve.correct3)
        print(" ")

        if i == 3:
            parameter = "media"
```

Comment: Hi! could you add a minimum reproducible example that showcases your error in the least (relevant) code possible?

Comment: It seems like `request_data` here does not have the amount of data you expect to have. You might want to check what you have before doing these operations or try using `try-except` blocks where you access the data.
`TLDR`: a question might have less than 4 choices or you are accessing the data wrong.